# How To Remove the Spacing Between 2 widgets in a QBoxLayout(QBoxLayout.TopToBottom)

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am using PyQt5 for reference in which I have a `QBoxLayout` with the parameter `QBoxLayout.TopToBottom` and I am trying to remove the spacing between the widgets as shown:
[image]

I have tried using `QBoxLayout.setSpacing(0)` and `QBoxLayout.setContentMargins(0,0,0,0)` and even tried making a custom `QBoxLayout` class where I define those both in the init function but to no fix.
If you guys need anything else I can reformat/add onto this question. For the record those widgets under the labels are `QProgressbar`
UPDATE:
Here is the code for the image:

```
class LearnLeftPanelQBox(QBoxLayout):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__(QBoxLayout.TopToBottom)
            self.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
            self.setSpacing(0)

self.learnLeftPanelTitle=QLabel("Correct:")
            self.learnLeftPanelTopLayout.addWidget(self.learnLeftPanelTitle)
            self.learnLeftPanelTitle.setStyleSheet("font: 20pt Comic Sans MS; color: white;")
            self.learnLeftPanelTopLayout.addWidget(self.learnLeftPanelTitle)
            self.learnLeftPanelProgressCorrect=QProgressBar()
            self.learnLeftPanelProgressCorrect.setStyleSheet("font: 20pt Comic Sans MS; color: green;")
            self.learnLeftPanelTopLayout.addWidget(self.learnLeftPanelProgressCorrect)
            self.learnLeftPanelTitle=QLabel("Incorrect:")
            self.learnLeftPanelTopLayout.addWidget(self.learnLeftPanelTitle)
            self.learnLeftPanelTitle.setStyleSheet("font: 20pt Comic Sans MS; color: white;")
            self.learnLeftPanelProgressIncorrect=QProgressBar()
            self.learnLeftPanelProgressIncorrect.setStyleSheet("font: 20pt Comic Sans MS; color: red;")
            self.learnLeftPanelTopLayout.addWidget(self.learnLeftPanelProgressIncorrect)
            self.learnLeftPanelLayout.addWidget(self.learnLeftPanelTop)
            self.learnLeftPanelSettingsButton=QPushButton("Settings")
            self.learnLeftPanelSettingsButton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{font: 20pt Comic Sans MS; color: white;border-style: outset; border-width: 2px; border-radius: 10px;border-color:white;} QPushButton::hover{background-color: white; color: black;}")
            self.learnLeftPanelSettingsButton.clicked.connect(self._showLearnSettings)
            self.learnLeftPanelLayout.addWidget(self.learnLeftPanelSettingsButton)
```

The tab formatting here is messed up but stack overflow isn't letting me fix it. These are all found in a separate function and the rest has no relation to this.

My best reproducible answer:

```
# Purpose: Stack layout example
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QLabel,QProgressBar,QApplication,QBoxLayout
class main(QWidget):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.showFullScreen()
        layout=QBoxLayout(QBoxLayout.TopToBottom)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        firstLabel=QLabel("First Label")
        firstBar=QProgressBar()
        secondLabel=QLabel("Second Label")
        secondBar=QProgressBar()
        layout.addWidget(firstLabel)
        layout.addWidget(firstBar)
        layout.addWidget(secondLabel)
        layout.addWidget(secondBar)
        self.setLayout(layout)
if __name__=="__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = main()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Could you add the code corresponding to the picture you have posted ?

Comment: Disregard the tab issue but here it is

Comment: @user19926715 Please try to explain your problem better, as it's unclear right now: why do you think that the first is correct and the second is not? Also, is the image a screenshot of the full widget/window? If not, add the *full* image of that. Finally, please provide a valid [mre], as your snippet references objects we know nothing about.

Comment: Sorry they were meant to be together. I need to remove the space between the QLabel and the QProgressbar although on the Layout I removed all the margins and spacings and that was why I was asking. The picture is part of the fullscreen window which was the only related part.

Comment: here is my best example. If the window was smaller the Layout places them next to each other but on fullscreen it shows the spacing I was talking about

Comment: @user19926715 It looks like you just need to add a stretchable spacer to the end of the layout (i.e. after adding all the widgets): `self.learnLeftPanelTopLayout.addStretch()`.

Comment: @user19926715 Sorry but your explanation is still a bit confusing. Most importantly, I still don't understand why the two spacings are inconsistent. Maybe, what you actually wanted to point out is that there are spacings between the labels and the progress bar, but not between the progress bar and the button (or the bottom of the window), which is a very different thing. If that's the case, you may try to add a stretch to the bottom (or *before* the button in your original example), but this will unfortunately push all contents to the top, which may not be what you actually want.

Comment: @user19926715 Note that all this is because each widget type has different *size policies*. QLabel has a `Preferred` vertical policy, meaning that it will eventually take as much available space there is, while other widgets like buttons (or QProgressBar) have a *fixed* vertical policy. This means that the progress bar will only take the vertical space required by their size hints, allowing the labels to take all the remaining. Equally distributing all those widgets is possible, but it has to be done by carefully considering these aspects.

Comment: @musicamante I wanted to know why the space between the widgets was there, but the size hint subject I wasn't aware of and will further test this and let you know if it fixes the issue.

Comment: @user19926715 I understood what you wanted to know, but you also have to understand that size and layout management is a very complex subject, and we cannot give valid answers if your references (the code and the image) don't match, because every widget type can have quite different behavior, and the sum of the behavior of each item that may affect the overall layout. Every item in a layout can have different requirements and capabilities, and the purpose of a layout manager is exactly to *manage* all that and eventually *lay out* them appropriately.

Comment: @musicamante That makes sense, so what do the layout managers have to use to determine these behaviors

Comment: @user19926715 Layouts consider the [`sizeHint()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#sizeHint-prop) (the *preferred* size) and [`sizePolicy()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#sizePolicy-prop) (how the layout may eventually use the hint above, possibly allocating less or more space), eventually considering their `minimumSizeHint()`, `minimumSize()` (if set) or `maximumSize()` (if set). For instance, buttons have a `Fixed` vertical policy, the layout will always allocate the height of their size hint; labels have `Preferred` vertical/horizontal policy, so if there's space left, they *can* use it.

Comment: Other widgets have an `Expanding` policy, meaning that will always take precedence to widgets with `Preferred` policies if there's space left in the layout, increasing their size accordingly. Finally, layouts use *stretch factors* which can be used to change the way the available space can be distributed. I suggest you to carefully read the documentation about [layout managers](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) and do some experiments in Qt Designer using different widget types and trying to change their size policies, so that you can better understand all these aspects.